# Oracle SQL Operator >= has higher performance than >

Tags: sql, database, oracle, performance

I got asked one question in interview.

Below two SQL will get same result. but which one have higher performance?

```
SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE DEPTNO >= 4

SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE DEPTNO > 3
```

The answer is first one . 
In first  SQL , Database will locate DEPT =4 directly where searching. it has higher performance.
In second SQL , Database will locate DEPT =3, and forwardly scan  row which is larger than 3 .

It is my first time heard that theory. I can't see any difference form execute plan and stat number.

Is there any official explanation for it ?

I found some Chinese website share the same tips.

http://edm.ares.com.tw/dm/newsletter-2014-03-uPKI-OTP-newrelease/it-1.php

Comment: In Oracle version 0.1 maybe? Oracle's CBO has capabilities to rewrite queries, so this wouldn't hold true today if it was even true.

Comment: I don't get the explanation - is there any index maybe?

Comment: I would agree if there was an index on A (without digging into the optimizer)

Comment: Assuming you're talking about b-tree indexes, [look at the internal structure](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28271_01/server.1111/e25789/indexiot.htm#CNCPT1170). It'll only look at the leaf nodes starting with the first that includes > 2, and the branch nodes followed to find that first leaf node will mean the same amount of work is done. (Although I suppose as it's a number, not integer column, the second could query could actually return more data...). If there is no index it's doing a full table scan for both.

Comment: Even if this explanation was true we're talking about microseconds to increment a counter. I've just profiled (slower than normal) this 1m times in PL/SQL (so a lot slower than C). It took 0.531 seconds of which 205/279 of the time was spend incrementing a counter to ensure PL/SQL didn't optimise the entire loop away. This implies that a single increment in PL/SQL (slow remember) is approx 1.4xE-7 seconds, i.e. 140ns. So small that it's irrelevant - assuming the theory is even true.

Comment: Come to think of it, if the table does hold integers from 1 to 10000, it'll do a full index scan or full table scan for both queries anyway... This may be the point where you remember that you are interviewing them as a prospective employer, as well as them interviewing you.

Comment: I second Alex on that point.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that the two queries are only equivalent if `DEPTNO` is an integer. Admittedly, `DEPTNO` probably is, but, in my experience, the need to optimize an inequality is more likely to occur on a `date` column, in which case assuming that the two are equivalent is more perilous.

Comment: Now that I've thought about it a little more, there's another implicit assumption: that the value `4` is found in the relevant column. If the value doesn't exist, then the theoretical gain is lost.

Answer (score 2):

I find that to be a myth if the column has an index on that field. I tried with a primary key and both execution plans use an Index Range Scan which is quite fast on a primary key or unique index. The two queries performance is extremely close to each other and both return a similar cost, but the one with ">"  was 0.3% better on the estimated CPU cost than ">=". I say BUSTED!

Besides, when I say something performs better, normally I would mean 10%+ if not more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but if you created an index having large PCTFREE, and if you were able to force to have the value 3 in one leaf block, while the value 4 was in another leaf block. (This can be validated via `ALTER DATABASE DUMP BLOCK`). And if you forced Oracle to use index range scan.

Then maybe you could see from the trace that one query processed one more page than the other one.